# program does not enter the method

Tags: android, location, overriding

i have problem , getCloudDistance() method in my project is never called , when i use breakpoint to debugging my project reach at this line `query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {`and then leave the method and return to onLoccationChanged() method ! what i can do to solve this problem ???!

```
    @Override


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Location net_loc, gps_loc;
                gps_loc = location;
                while (gps_loc != null) {
                    showCurrentLocation(gps_loc);
                    getCloudDistance(location) ;
                }

 public void getCloudDistance(final Location location) {




    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ServerBumps");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     //   @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                    Location locationA = new Location("A");
                    locationA.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                    locationA.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

                    /*Location locationA = new Location("A");
                    locationA.setLatitude(32.3109337);
                    locationA.setLongitude(35.0284839);
                    */
                    Location locationB = new Location("B");
                    double lan= Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getString("Lan"));
                    double lon=Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getString("Lon"));

                    locationB.setLatitude(lan);
                    locationB.setLongitude(lon);
                    distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

                    if (distance <= radius) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Bump", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        player.start();
                    }

                }
            }


        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint inside of `done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e)`

Comment: i put breakpoint inside done() ,but it is not up to this line and leave getCloudDistance() method

Comment: Since it's doing it in the background, it may take time to reach `done()` what happens if your only set breakpoint is inside of `done()`?

Comment: its leave this method and go to showCurrentLocation(gps_loc);once more

Comment: Maybe there is some exception, try to log the `e` message in else case (when `e!=null`).